# How do you get rid of errno 150 when creating a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

So to start off, I looked at other posts with the same errno 150 issue and the answers seem to be very different as errno 150 is quite ambiguous.

So this is my code

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GAME;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CONSOLE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEVELOPER;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RATING;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

CREATE TABLE GAME(
    Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Console VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Release_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Genre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Max_Players TINYINT NOT NULL,
    Developer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Rating VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Title, Console)
);

CREATE TABLE CONSOLE(
    Company VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Console VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Num_Of_Controllers TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Console),
    FOREIGN KEY(Console) REFERENCES GAME(Console) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE DEVELOPER(
    Developer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Region VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Developer),
    FOREIGN KEY(Developer) REFERENCES GAME(Developer) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE ESRB(
    Rating VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    Age TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Rating),
    FOREIGN KEY(Rating) REFERENCES GAME(ESRB) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

but once this is run, I get an error

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 19: Can't create table '<database_name>.CONSOLE' (errno: 150)
```

Other posts had an issue of foreign key checks which is why I change the foreign key check flag in the beginning of the query. Does anyone have any idea what to do?

I'm guessing that it's an issue of foreign key references since the GAME table is created just fine but I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated

Edit:

I have also tried to use ALTER TABLE at the end of all the creations to add the foreign key but I still get the same errno 150.

Comment: First your gane table has no column **ESRB**, every foreign key has to have a Index on the table if references

Comment: Change `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RATING;`  to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ESRB;` and the code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code has foreign key declarations like:

```
CREATE TABLE ESRB(
    Rating VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    Age TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Rating),
    FOREIGN KEY(Rating) REFERENCES GAME(ESRB) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

I suspect that you are mixing things here.

You want the `GAME` table to have foreign keys towards the other tables, not the other way around.

So you should move the declarations of foreign keys from tables `CONSOLE`, `DEVELOPER` and `ESRB` to the `GAME` table, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE GAME(
    Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Console VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Release_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Genre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Max_Players TINYINT NOT NULL,
    Developer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Rating VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Title, Console),
    FOREIGN KEY(Console) REFERENCES CONSOLE(Console) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(Developer) REFERENCES DEVELOPER(Developer) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(Rating) REFERENCES ESRB(Rating) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

This gives you a set-up where values in columns `Console`, `Developer` and `Rating` must belong to the respective referrential tables. I believe that *this* is what you want.

Also, since this table now referrences the 3 other tables, it should be created last, not first.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6CuRo8T8utrW6H3TRTYsgg/0)**